# Problem when trying to click with puppeter

Tags: javascript, instagram, puppeteer

As the title says, I'm creating an application to automate my instagram with the puppeteer and I came to this button, which I can't click.

I've tried using page.waitForSelector and page.click and nothing works ... My last attempt was:

`await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});`

`await page.evaluate(() => { document.querySelector('a.-nal3').click(); });`

Image of where I want to click:

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: `await page.waitForNavigation()` may block clicking. Try `await Promise.all([page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0'}), page.evaluate(() => { document.querySelector('a.-nal3').click(); })])` or `await Promise.all([page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0'}),  elementHandle.click()])`

Comment: Could you elaborate did you get any error or just after clicking on the element nothing happening? If the last, then ensure that the element that you're looking for is unique as sometimes it can be a similar hidden element. Also, try to find and click not at the `a` tag but on its parent.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be trying to click in the page context, but in the puppeteer context. You can use [`waitForSelector`](https://devdocs.io/puppeteer/index#pagewaitforselectorselector-options) to get a handle to the element itself, then click on it with [`<elementHandle>.click`](https://devdocs.io/puppeteer/index#elementhandleclickoptions)

```
const [link] = await page.waitForSelector('a.-na13');
if (link) {
    await link.click();
}
```

Comment: At first I even thought that this would be the problem ... But I had already tested a similar command, I tested yours and got the same problem.

Comment: If the above code isn't working, the css query must be failing. Have you tried using xpath instead of css selectors?